# cocoapods pod lib create and schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using the latest [beta cocoapods](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/) release that support frameworks with xcode 6.1.1, `sudo gem install cocoapods --prerelease`

I then ran `pod lib create podtry` to create a sample app, no demo app, no testing framework, no view based testing. I then opened it in xcode and notice that it created 3 schemes, `pods-podtry, pods-podtry-podtry-podtry, podtry-Example` and 2 Pods targets, `Pods-podtry, Pods-podtry-podtry-podtry`. Can someone explain why there are 2 targets and 3 schemes? It seems like ony `Pods-podtry-podtry-podtry` target contains the `plist.info` version specified in podspec `s.version` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I figured this out, hopefully this will help someone new to cocoapods. There are 2 targets and each of the scheme has one of the 2 targets. For example, `podtry-Example` scheme has `Pods-podtry` target plus `test`action has `podtry` test added. `Pods-podtry-podtry-podtry` scheme has `Pods-podtry-podtry-podtry` target but no `test` action. `Pods-podtry` scheme has `Pods-podtry` target, no `test` action but has a target dependency on `Pods-podtry-podtry-podtry`. Phew that's a mouthful but there it is.

There are a couple of things I still don't quite get though

1. Why did cocoapods create `Pods-podtry` target that builds a `Pods_podtry.framework` in addition to `podtry.framework`. Ultimately I am only interested in `podtry.framework` and I am not sure about the purpose of `Pods_podtry.framework`.
2. Why did cocoapods not create a test target like xcode normally does for a new project, instead it make that a test action target dependency.

Any insights will be much appreciated.